# Partitions with multiplicity locally restricted

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I am interested in finding any **result, paper, taxonomy, generating function, bijection...** on what I call "**Partitions with multiplicity locally restricted**" that is partitions in which multiplicity of each part is restricted according to the multiplicity of the previous (smaller) ones in some recursive way.

For instance: Partitions in which number of 2's is smaller than number of 1's and number of 3's is smaller that the number of 2's and so on.

Additionaly I note that restriction on multiplicity does not necessarily involve downward multiplicity if additional upper bound on largest part size is also restricted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely understand what you are asking for but suppose $4+3+3+2+2+1+1+1+1+1 = 1\times4 +2\times3+2\times2+5\times 1$ is an acceptable partition of $19$

Then this can be seen as a partition of $19$ into triangle numbers, equivalent to $10+6+1+1+1$ in this example

The number of such partitions is listed in [OEIS A007294](https://oeis.org/A007294), which gives some references and methods of calculation